# C#: Opening form after checking another forms status?

Tags: c#, button, splash-screen

At the start of my main form i have a thread for a splashscreen and timer.

```
public xMainForm()
{
    //start timer and bring in splashscreen
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SplashScreen));
    t.Start();            
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    InitializeComponent();
 }//end public xMainForm
```

That is all working fine. The timer on my splashscreen leads up to the initialization of my xMainForm and enables a button on my splashscreen.

```
private void xTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //use xTimer_Tick to give continuous countdown
    if(countDown < 100)
    {
        countDown = countDown + 1;
        xCountLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(countDown);
    }
    else
    {
        xTimer.Stop();
        xCountLabel.Visible = false;
        xGoLabel.Visible=true;
    }
}//end xTimer
private void xGoLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}//end xGoLabel_Click
```

Is it possible to put in a statement on my main form to check to see if my splashscreen is still open, and if it is wait until it is closed before the main form initializes?

Essentially I want the timer to make the button appear and the button to show my main form upon clicking it.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think it'd be better to fire an event FROM your splash screen to let the main screen know it's done

Comment: Or really just put your splash screen in front and close it when it finishes, and don't worry about thread.sleep.  That would make it a real splash screen, as you could load your main form in the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can check that like

```
if (Application.OpenForms["yoursplashscreen"] != null)
{
     //splash screen is open
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use multiple threads in this application. If you only want to show one window at a time, use the following code in your `Program.cs`.

```
Application.Run(new SplashScreen());
Application.Run(new xMainForm());
```

Of course, that would not be a *real* splash screen, which should allow the main window to initialize while the splash is showing, but it would accomplish what you want to do.